# Java jar install trouble

Tags: java

I'm trying to use [charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/Download.html), and according to the instructions, I should just be able to point LD_LIBRARY_PATH to a shared library and put the jar on my classpath and then I should be able to use the library.

Yet while I have the jar on the classpath, the following code fails with "package charva does not exist":

```
import charva.awt;

class ...
```

when I attempt to compile it.

I'm probably messing this up because I have no experience with java packages: why am I getting a package does not exist message if the jar is on the classpath?

I'm pretty sure that the jar isn't broken as the library came with a test script and a demo which appeared to be working correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "import the library"?  Import into what?

Comment: I don't understand "install": Jars can't be installed, can they?

Comment: @Pindatjuh - I suspect he's trying to bring it into some IDE or other, or maybe into a web application server.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like my lack of knowledge in java is showing. I've edited for clarity.

Comment: what, exactly, is the error you get?

Comment: "test.java:1: package charva does not exist". I used javac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't point LD_LIBRARY_PATH to a shared library. You point it to a directory containing one or more of them.

Assuming that you have a .so for the right architecture, you need LD_LIBRARY_PATH as well as -Djava.library.path (unless the Java code is especially tricky).

More to the point, your question concerns a compile-time error. This has to just be that you didn't tell javac about the jar with -cp.

Comment: Thanks, I misspoke: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is pointing to the directory as it should be, and the import is still failing. As I said, I'm pretty sure that I have the correct .so as the library tests worked.